# What is the correct way to create a cryptographically secure ID in BOTH node.js and javascript without libraries?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, browser, cryptography

I'm tying to write an ES6 module that detects which environment it is running on and create a unique hex ID if it is node, or if it is browser. I do not want to use browser libraries or a bundler.

In node.js:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
let id = crypto.randomBytes(48, function(err, buffer) {
  return buffer.toString('hex')
})
console.log(id)
```

In both browser and node *without* a bundler:

```js
???? unsure, from on my research on how to accomplish the same thing.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node 15+](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/webcrypto.html) and [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/cryptography) support the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API)

```
export async function setupHexRandom(){
  const mycrypto = (typeof crypto !== 'undefined')
     ? crypto
     : (await import('node:crypto')).webcrypto

  if (!mycrypto) throw new Error('No crypto available or fallback to a Math.random implementation')

  return function hexRandom(){
    const bytes = mycrypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(48))
    return Array.from(bytes)
      .map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
      .join('')
  }
}

const hexRandom = await setupHexRandom()
console.log(hexRandom())
```

Comment: I prefer not to use a bundler for the browser. I am looking for code that works for both without a bundler.

Comment: The web crypto API doesn't require a bundler as it's available in both. You may need to do a conditional import for node, which would make the whole thing asyncronous.

Comment: Oh, I missed the `.webcryto` at the end. Thanks!